# Integrating a top heavy function

Tags: integration

How do you integrate this function?

$$\int\frac{x^3}{(x+5)^2}dx$$
I have tried it myself by substitution but I can't seem to get rid of the $x$s.

Comment: Instead of a substitution, try partial fractions.

Comment: tried as well but since the bottom has (x+5) twice, A and B will cancel meaning I can't find a value for them.

Comment: when I did long devision, I got: \int x+10 + \frac{75x+250}{(x+5)^2}\

Comment: You need to make a polynomial division first, since the partial fractions method requires the degree of the polynomial in the numerator to be lower that that in the denominator.  [OK, in your division, the quotient should be $ \ x - 10 \ $ ] .

Answer (score 12):

Hint: Rewrite it as $$\int \frac{(u-5)^3}{u^2}\text{d}u$$ by making the substitution $u = x+5$ and rearranging that until you can get $x$ (i.e., if $u = x+5$, then $x = ?$)

Comment: Much better than division followed by partial fractions, which I was going to post.

Comment: Right, :P ofcourse

Comment: Why didn't the obvious elementary way occur to me before partial fractions? +1

Comment: Because we see so many _irreducible_ quadratics in the denominator?

Answer (score 4):

Long division:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
& & x & - & 10 \\  \\
x^2+10x+25 & ) & x^3 \\
& & x^3 & + & 10x^2 & + & 25x \\  \\
& & & & -10x^2 & - & 25x \\
& & & & -10x^2 & - & 100x \\  \\
& & & & & & 75 x
\end{array}
$$

So we have
$$
\frac{x^3}{x^2+10x+25} = x - 10 + \frac{75x}{(x+5)^2} = x - 10 + \frac{A}{x-5} + \frac{B}{(x+5)^2}.
$$